# ExtJS getClass() to dynamically hide/show icon

Tags: extjs, dynamic, icons, sencha-architect

Using Sencha Architect I am attempting a grid with an action column.  The column has two possible icons which are hidden or displayed depending on a value in the grid row.  This is a well documented use case and I have tried to follow the example code as closely as I can but simply cannot get it to work.

```
            columns: [
            {
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                width: 50,
                dataIndex: 'IsFilter',
                items: [
                    {
                        getClass: function(v, metadata, r, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                            var isFilter = r.get('IsFilter');
                            if (!isFilter) {
                                return  "x-hide-display";
                            } else {
                                console.log(r.get('Title') + ' sort');
                                return "x-grid-center-icon";
                            }
                        },
                        icon: 'resources/Images/png/sort35.png'
                    },
                    {
                        getClass: function(v, metadata, r, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                            if (v) {
                                return "x-hide-display";
                            } else {
                                console.log(r.get('Title') + ' filter');
                                return "x-grid-center-icon";
                            }
                        },
                        icon: 'resources/Images/png/funnel6.png'
                    }
                ]
            }
```

I know the logic works as I see the correct console messages.  Desired outcome is to show one icon or the other.  Instead, it always shows both icons. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, I don't see x-hide-display as being a action item class. Have you added the code for x-hide-display to your CSS manually? If yes, please share the code here. If not, add `.x-hide-display { display: none;}` to your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The issue must be in the logic as when I simplify it and do this it works for me in changing around the true and false values.

```
    columns: [
        {
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            width: 50,
            dataIndex: 'IsFilter',
            items: [
                {
                    getClass: function(v, metadata, r, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                        if (true) {
                            return  "x-hide-display";
                        } else {
                            console.log(r.get('Title') + ' sort');
                            return "x-grid-center-icon";
                        }
                    },
                    icon: '/js/ext-3.4.0/resources/images/access/menu/unchecked.gif'
                },
                {
                    getClass: function(v, metadata, r, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                        if (false) {
                            return "x-hide-display";
                        } else {
                            console.log(r.get('Title') + ' filter');
                            return "x-grid-center-icon";
                        }
                    },
                    icon: '/js/ext-3.4.0/resources/images/access/menu/checked.gif'
                }
            ]
        },
```

Check to see if `r.get('IsFilter');` and `if (v) {` are actually returning what you would expect and at the right times.

Comment: thank you for your answer.  Frustratingly, when I likewise simplify the logic I still see both icons.  I'm convinced the logic is okay and the value being passed is correct.

Comment: have you overrided the css at all?

Comment: I am trying now to add new css class of showIconSort and showIconFilter but have not made it work yet.  Is your opinion to do an override?

Comment: Okay.  As I suspected, I was doing something stupid.  I am working in Sencha Architect. What I needed to do is build 2 ActionColumnItems off the single ActionColumn.  Then it all worked!

Comment: This is not working for me on ExtJs 5 but I have got it working on ExtJs 4. Anyone has done this on 5?

Comment: @code4jhon I haven't tried this in ExtJS 5, if you post a question regarding your issue I'll take a look at it, please link it here

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you are adding both the icons in the items.Instead add the icons in the CSS class i.e.,  in your *x-grid-center-icon* and *x-hide-display* and return that class based on your condition.

Code looks like below .

```
columns: [
            {
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                width: 50,
                dataIndex: 'IsFilter',
                items: [
                    {
                        getClass: function(v, metadata, r, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                            var isFilter = r.get('IsFilter');
                            if (!isFilter) {
                                return  "hideDisplay";
                            } else {
                                console.log(r.get('Title') + ' sort');
                                return "showIcon";
                            }
                        },

                    },
                    {
                        getClass: function(v, metadata, r, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                            if (v) {
                                return "hideDisplay";
                            } else {
                                console.log(r.get('Title') + ' filter');
                                return "showIcon";
                            }
                        },

                    }
                ]
            }


CSS add the following :


    .hideDisplay
    {
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
      background-image:none;
    }

    .showIcon
    {
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
      background-image:resources/Images/png/sort35.png
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: overriding default Ext classes and adding images to them would not be a good idea, those classes are used a lot with ExtJs and you don't want those icons showing everywhere. only in place. Your answer could be greatly improved by adding an id to the parent menu and then only overriding the CSS within that selector such as `#my-menu .x-hide-display {...`